# Can Spring IDE support editing multiple application.yml files?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-ide

I'm using `Eclipse Neon` with `Spring IDE Version 3.8.3.201612191259-RELEASE`.
Whenever I create an `application.yml` file under `src/main/resources` it shows with a Spring embellished icon and allows me to see Spring Boot's configuration (for example see here: https://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v370/NewAndNoteworthy.html).

For different profiles developers can either use a single YAML file with different sections for each `spring.profiles` via the `---` notation.  Developers might also choose to use separate YAML files named with the profile as part of the name (i.e. `application-dev.yml`) as noted in this link: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profile-based-properties-and-yaml-example/ .

The functionality provided by the `Spring Boot YML Editor` is very helpful not only for YAML editing but also because it allows auto-complete for Spring Boot's configuration.   Is there a way to associate more than one file to be see by the `Spring Boot YML Editor` so that I can easily edit files like `application-dev.yml` in that editor?  I know I can right-click on the file and have it open-with Spring Yaml Properties Editor but it would be nice if similar to configuring the Spring Bean support Config Files you could also pick multiple files to be seen as Spring YAML files (or perhaps look for all `application-XXX.yml` files and associate them to the editor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The place where to specify file associations for the content type `Spring Yaml Properties File` can be found in the Eclipse preferences in `General > Content Types`. Search for the content type `Yaml Content Type > Spring Yaml Properties File`. In the box below you can add your required file associations.

As of Eclipse Neon you have to specify all your variants, e.g. `application-prod.yml`, `application-some-profile.yml`, ...

In Eclipse Photon it will be possible to use wildcards, e.g. `application-*.yml`. See https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/M2/ for details